# Take non-null values from 2 columns in 7-column table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have an SQLite table such as this:

[image: Table]

Each row represents an object, and columns B - G represent data the object holds. As you can see, only columns B and C are gauranteed to be non-null.

What I want to do is to get all non-null data from columns E and F, in a first-in-first-out method (if both E and F have non-null values, we'll just take E first). I want to take the non-null values and add them to an `ArrayList<String>` object and then return the array. So, for the above table, my `ArrayList` would look like `[String1, String2, String3, String4]`.

Below is what I have so far, but my program crashes. I think the array that is being returned is null for some reason.

**UPDATE:** The `rawQuery` below does not work. When Column E is non-null and Column F is null, this returns an array similar to: `[String, null]`. This was verified by taking the size of the array afterward, which came out to 2, and then trying to loop through it in a `try/catch`. The first element worked fine, but the second element threw a `NullPointerException`.

```
db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

ArrayList<String> array= new ArrayList<String>();

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + COLUMN_E + ", " + COLUMN_F + " FROM " 
                            + MY_TABLE + " WHERE " + COLUMN_E + " IS NOT NULL OR "
                            + COLUMN_F + " IS NOT NULL", null);

if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
{
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    do
    {
        array.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_E)));
        array.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_F)));
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    cursor.close();
}

return array;
```

Can anyone please help me out? Thank you!

Logcat when E is not null, F is null. The same occurs when F is non-null and E is null, and also when both are non-null. The exception occurs in another class when I try to convert the ArrayList to a String array:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array`

Comment: Can you upload the Logcat?

Comment: @joaquin I'll run it a few times and post the logcats

Comment: Did you check any of the variables are not null? Can you check the same rawQuery but without the IS NOT NULL conditions?

Comment: I'm sure the variables are not null, because at least one of columns D, E, F, or G must be non-null to reach this point, and I am testing by only entering data into E and/or F. Running the same rawQuery without the IS NOT NULL conditions still had the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a UNION clause to join the results from 2 queries:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery
    (
        "SELECT " + COLUMN_E + " AS myField FROM " + MY_TABLE + " WHERE " + COLUMN_E + " IS NOT NULL " + 
        "UNION " + 
        "SELECT " + COLUMN_F + " AS myField FROM " + MY_TABLE + " WHERE " + COLUMN_F + " IS NOT NULL ", null
    );
```

So you will get a single column resultset containing a field named myField, which collects the non-null values from Column_E **AND** the non-null values from Column_F.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. After I execute the `rawQuery`, how could I get the data from `myField` and add it to an array? I'm not sure how to work with a mono-column.

Comment: It's simply a query which retuns one field only. I called it mono-column (not an official term), to indicate it has a single field in it. So, use it as a normal query result: `array.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("myField")));`

Answer (score 1):

Test if the returned column is null or not before inserting it in the arraylist. There is an isNull() method, to detect null-values.